# How can I use AVCaptureStillImageOutput to capture just part of the screen?

Tags: iphone, avfoundation, avcapturesession

When I capture a still image, it's a full-screen image, if I want just some rect on the preview screen to be captured into a image, how can I do  this?

Answer (score 0):

checkout this link https://github.com/BeauNouvelle/AspectFillFaceAware It will automatically detect face in image and automatically adjust that portion in centre.